How to add dotted underline for each line in multi-line list items
I just found a theme that look like a note pad. I need to fill that listed item with a text and whenever it reach the end of each line should have a breakline to the next listed item with the same design
Here is an example of my theme


body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

h4 {
  color: #cd0000;
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-align: left;
}

.list {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 1000px;
  font-family: courier, monospace;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-indent: 25px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.list li:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
}

.lines {
  border-left: 1px solid #ffaa9f;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffaa9f;
  width: 2px;
  float: left;
  height: 495px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
<div class="lines"></div>

<ul class="list">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>



I also want to view this list item in the center of my page that shows as note page is filled with description
after I find the solution, I want to implement it to my web application that I am developing in express, node js where I can loop around each listed item and bring in the description from my mongo database
Please any help would be appreciated!

To clarify, you mean you want the individual breaked lines in the same <li> to have the dotted under line and hover effects as if they are separated into multiple list items?

no need to hover just to continue the text in the next dotted line. Think of it as you are writing in a paper and filling your words under each dotted lines

Thanks for replying. Could you please clarify the requirement in your question?

if you run the code, you could see the listed items is showing! I want the same design to be viewed for my text. so for example at the end of each line should have a breakline into the next listed item. I think this could have the same result if I changed some of my css

Yeah I get it, I was asking to edit the your question is for clarification for other people that is looking at this post, since your original clarification is under a deleted post. Especially in this case the solution is outside my knowledge.

Thanks @SyndRain I will be using the text decoration as you stated and try to fix the margin of the text. if it possible bring again your solution to vote over it!

Thanks for replying. Though I would suggest you could wait if someone else have better solution. I've mentioned text decoration because I thought that's the effect you need.  A repeating linear-gradient background with height 1lh might be doable, I just don't know how to make it dotted.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

To make each line in a multiline list item having the same dotted underline as if they are broken into individual listed item, the closest I can get is to use a linear-gradient background.


body {
  --background-color: 245, 245, 245;
  background-color: rgb(var(--background-color));
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

h4 {
  color: #cd0000;
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-align: left;
}

.list {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 1000px;
  font-family: courier, monospace;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.list li {
  --dot-color: 204, 204, 204;
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 25px;
  min-height: 1lh;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  --line-background: var(--background-color);
  background-color: rgb(var(--line-background));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(var(--line-background), 1) 0, rgba(var(--line-background), 1) 50%, rgba(var(--dot-color), 0) calc(50% + 1px), rgba(var(--dot-color), 0) 100%), linear-gradient(to top, rgb(var(--dot-color)) 0 1px, rgb(var(--line-background)) 1px 100%);
  background-size: 2px 1lh;
}

.list li:hover {
  --line-background: 240, 240, 240;
  /* transition: all 0.2s; */
}

.lines {
  border-left: 1px solid #ffaa9f;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffaa9f;
  width: 2px;
  float: left;
  height: 495px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
<div class="lines"></div>

<ul class="list">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>




Use text-decoration to achieve the same dotted underline effect.
.list li {
  text-decoration: underline dotted #ccc 1px;
}



body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

h4 {
  color: #cd0000;
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-align: left;
}

.list {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 1000px;
  font-family: courier, monospace;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-indent: 25px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: underline dotted #ccc 1px;
}

.list li:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
}

.lines {
  border-left: 1px solid #ffaa9f;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffaa9f;
  width: 2px;
  float: left;
  height: 495px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
<div class="lines"></div>

<ul class="list">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>



